# White page with MVC4+ on IIS 7.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7, web-config

**The problem**:
When creating a new ASP.NET MVC site, when deployed on production or stage, the server returns empty white pages.

To develop we use Visual Studio 2012 and the sites are created using the MVC 4 template and we have IIS 7.5 or 8.0 depending on the version of Windows.

Production and stage servers are running Windows Server 2008 with IIS 7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The cause**

What we found out is that since IIS 7.5 some parts of the web.config are moved into the default configuration. Also, the web site template either assumes the IIS version or creates a web.config based on IIS 7.5. That means that when you deploy the site on a server running IIS 7.0, the problem will occur.

**The solution**
Simply go in the web.config and add this line

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

in the `<system.webServer />` section

Comment: @RonenFestinger the question is explicitly tagged for MVC 4

Comment: Ok, I just mentioned it to let people know it doesn't work with mvc 6, What worked for me was to disable the application error event in the global.asax.  Blank screen happens when there is an exception, by this way you will see the exception on screen.

Answer (score 0):

When i using One Click publish
After setup again server . I need `click publish again` and everything is working as desired