# Anyone know what happens with my Layout in ASP. NET?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

You see, I have a problem. I have configured my file ***"BundleConfig.cs"*** to minify my styles and scripts in production. At this moment I am in the development environment. My application had some performance problems by the dependencies. At first I had pages and called unnecessary resources, such as style sheets and / or scripts, now I am correcting that. In this stage I have had a problem that I can not skip since a day ago. My Customers page (list of them) is having problems loading, which does not happen with my Dashboard; obviously they use the same Layout (Master Page). I think it's something referring to my call to JQUERY but I still do not get the answer. My project is made with ASP .NET MVC 5 and I use Visual Studio 2015. It would be great if they helped me. Thank you very much.

[White screen in one of views with the same layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7Tzr.jpg)

***BundleConfig.cs***

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace Acisac
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            /*  ----------------------------------- CSS  ------------------------------------------ */
            StyleBundle bootstrapCSS = new StyleBundle("~/css/bootstrap");
            bootstrapCSS.Include("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css");
            //bootstrapCSS.Include("~/Content/template/tether/tether.min.css");

            StyleBundle mainCSS = new StyleBundle("~/css/mainCSS");
            mainCSS.Include("~/fonts/css.css");
            mainCSS.Include("~/Content/template/main.css");

            //mainCSS.Include("~/Content/template/animate.min.css");

            StyleBundle fontsCSS = new StyleBundle("~/css/fonts");
            fontsCSS.Include(
                "~/fonts/css.css",
                "~/fonts/font-awesome-icons.min.css",
                "~/fonts/ionicons-icons.min.css",
                "~/fonts/material-design-iconic-font.min.css",
                "~/fonts/other-fonts.css"
                );
            StyleBundle materiagrisCSS = new StyleBundle("~/css/materiagris");
            materiagrisCSS.Include("~/Content/materiagris/materia03.css");
            materiagrisCSS.Include("~/Content/materiagris/materia1.css");
            materiagrisCSS.Include("~/Content/materiagris/materia02.css");

            StyleBundle chartsCSS = new StyleBundle("~/css/charts");
            chartsCSS.Include("~/Content/template/charts/chartist.min.css");

            StyleBundle footableCSS = new StyleBundle("~/css/footable");
            footableCSS.Include("~/Util/footable/footable.bootstrap.min.css");

            bundles.Add(fontsCSS);
            bundles.Add(bootstrapCSS);
            bundles.Add(materiagrisCSS);
            bundles.Add(mainCSS);
            bundles.Add(chartsCSS);
            bundles.Add(footableCSS);

            /*  -----------------------------------   JS  scripts ------------------------------------------ */
            /***************************************JQUERY***************************************/
            ScriptBundle jqueryJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/jquery");
            jqueryJS.Include("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js");
            /***************************************BOOTSTRAP***************************************/
            ScriptBundle bootstrapJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/bootstrap");
            bootstrapJS.Include("~/Scripts/template/pluginsGenerales/tether.min.js");
            bootstrapJS.Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js");
            /***************************GENERALES PARA TODA LA APLICACIÓN***************************/
            ScriptBundle mainJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/mainJS");
            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/template/pluginsGenerales/jquery.storageapi.min.js");
            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/template/pluginsGenerales/jquery.fullscreen.min.js");
            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/template/pluginsGenerales/pace.min.js");
            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/template/pluginsGenerales/wow.min.js");

            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/template/scriptsGenerales/main.js");
            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/template/scriptsGenerales/colors.js");
            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/template/scriptsGenerales/functions.js");
            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/template/scriptsGenerales/left-sidebar.js");
            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/template/scriptsGenerales/navbar.js");

            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris1/comboBoxes.js");
            mainJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris2/Validacion.js");
            /***********************************CASOS ESPECÍFICOS***********************************/
            //GRAFICOS
            ScriptBundle chartsJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/charts");
            chartsJS.Include(
                "~/Scripts/template/charts/Chart.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/template/charts/chartist.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/template/charts/charts-chartist.js",
                "~/Scripts/template/charts/jquery.easypiechart.min.js",
                 "~/Scripts/template/charts/lodash.min.js"
                );
            //FOOTABLE
            ScriptBundle footableJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/footable");
            footableJS.Include("~/Util/footable/footable.min.js");
            footableJS.Include("~/Util/utilitarios.js");
            /****************************************LOGIN****************************************/
            ScriptBundle loginJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/login");
            loginJS.IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/template/login", "*.js");
            /**************************************DASHBOARD**************************************/
            ScriptBundle dashboardJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/dashboard");
            dashboardJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris4/diagramaBarras.js");
            dashboardJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris4/crudInicio.js");
            /***************************************VENTAS***************************************/
            ScriptBundle cotizacionJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/cotizacion");
            cotizacionJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris2/ConsultasAjax.js");

            ScriptBundle ordenVentaJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/ordenVenta");
            ordenVentaJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris2/ConsultasAjax.js");
            ordenVentaJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris2/crudOrdenVenta.js");

            ScriptBundle facturacionJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/facturacion");
            facturacionJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris1/crudFacturacion.js");

            //ScriptBundle guiaVentasJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/guiaVentas");
            //guiaVentasJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudGuia.js");
            /**************************************ALMACEN**************************************/
            ScriptBundle guiaAlmacenJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/guiaAlmacen");
            guiaAlmacenJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris3/crudGuia.js");

            //ScriptBundle productoAlmacenJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/productoAlmacen");
            //productoAlmacenJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudProductoAlmacen.js");

            ScriptBundle notaIngresoJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/notaIngreso");
            notaIngresoJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris3/crudNotaIngreso.js");

            ScriptBundle notaSalidaJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/notaSalida");
            notaSalidaJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris3/crudNotaSalida.js");
            /**************************************COMPRAS**************************************/
            //ScriptBundle ordenCompraJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/ordenCompra");
            //ordenCompraJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudOrdenCompra.js");
            /**************************************CUENTAS**************************************/
            ScriptBundle reciboJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/recibo");
            reciboJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris1/crudRecibo.js");

            ScriptBundle convenioJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/convenio");
            convenioJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris2/agregarConvenio.js");
            //convenioJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudConvenio.js");
            /***********************************MANTENIMIENTO***********************************/
            ScriptBundle clienteJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/cliente");
            clienteJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris1/crudCliente.js");
            clienteJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris2/ContactoNuevo.js");
            clienteJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris2/DireccionNuevo.js");

            ScriptBundle proveedorJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/proveedor");
            proveedorJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris3/crudProveedor.js");

            ScriptBundle empleadoJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/empleado");
            empleadoJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris4/crudEmpleado.js");

            ScriptBundle almacenJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/almacen");
            almacenJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris1/crudAlmacen.js");

            ScriptBundle anaquelJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/anaquel");
            anaquelJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris1/crudAnaquel.js");

            ScriptBundle familiaJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/familia");
            familiaJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris3/crudFamilia.js");

            ScriptBundle productoMantenimientoJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/productoMantenimiento");
            productoMantenimientoJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris1/crudProducto.js");
            clienteJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris2/AgregarCaracteristica.js");

            ScriptBundle marcaJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/marca");
            marcaJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris3/crudFamilia.js");

            ScriptBundle unidadJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/unidad");
            unidadJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris1/crudUnidad.js");

            ScriptBundle cambioJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/cambio");
            cambioJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris1/crudTipocambio.js");

            ScriptBundle impuestoJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/impuesto");
            impuestoJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris3/crudFamilia.js");
            /***********************************TRANSPORTE***********************************/
            ScriptBundle etransporteJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/etransporte");
            etransporteJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris1/crudEmpresaTransporte.js");

            //ScriptBundle vehiculoJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/vehiculo");
            //vehiculoJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudVehiculo.js");

            //ScriptBundle conductorJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/conductor");
            //conductorJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudConductor.js");
            /***********************************REPORTES***********************************/
            //ScriptBundle reporteJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/reporte");
            //reporteJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudReporte.js");
            /********************************G. DE USUARIOS********************************/
            //ScriptBundle perfilJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/perfil");
            //perfilJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudPerfil.js");

            //ScriptBundle usuarioJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/usuario");
            //usuarioJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudUsuario.js");
            /***********************************CONFIGURACION***********************************/
            //ScriptBundle empresaJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/empresa");
            //empresaJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudEmpresa.js");
            //ScriptBundle serieJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/serie");
            //serieJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudSerie.js");
            //ScriptBundle bancoJS = new ScriptBundle("~/js/banco");
            //bancoJS.Include("~/Scripts/materiagris/materiagris[#]/crudBanco.js");

            bundles.Add(jqueryJS);
            bundles.Add(bootstrapJS);
            bundles.Add(mainJS);
            bundles.Add(chartsJS);
            bundles.Add(footableJS);
            bundles.Add(loginJS);
            bundles.Add(dashboardJS);
            bundles.Add(cotizacionJS);
            bundles.Add(ordenVentaJS);
            bundles.Add(facturacionJS);
            //bundles.Add(guiaVentasJS);
            bundles.Add(guiaAlmacenJS);
            //bundles.Add(productoAlmacenJS);
            bundles.Add(notaIngresoJS);
            bundles.Add(notaSalidaJS);
            //bundles.Add(ordenCompraJS);
            bundles.Add(reciboJS);
            bundles.Add(convenioJS);
            bundles.Add(clienteJS);
            bundles.Add(proveedorJS);
            bundles.Add(empleadoJS);
            bundles.Add(almacenJS);
            bundles.Add(anaquelJS);
            bundles.Add(familiaJS);
            bundles.Add(productoMantenimientoJS);
            bundles.Add(marcaJS);
            bundles.Add(unidadJS);
            bundles.Add(cambioJS);
            bundles.Add(impuestoJS);
            bundles.Add(etransporteJS);
            //bundles.Add(vehiculoJS);
            //bundles.Add(conductorJS);
            //bundles.Add(reporteJS);
            //bundles.Add(perfilJS);
            //bundles.Add(usuarioJS);
            //bundles.Add(empresaJS);
            //bundles.Add(serieJS);
            //bundles.Add(bancoJS);  
        }
    }
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>ACISAC - @ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="~/Assets/icon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/Assets/icon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

    <!-- CSS -->
    @Styles.Render("~/css/fonts")
    @Styles.Render("~/css/bootstrap")
    @Styles.Render("~/css/mainCSS")
    @Styles.Render("~/css/materiagris")
    <!-- ------ -->
    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    @Scripts.Render("~/js/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/js/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/js/mainJS")
    <!-- ------ -->
</head>

<body data-layout="empty-layout" data-palette="palette-6" data-direction="none">
    <div class="main">
        <!--header-->
        @Html.Partial("_header")
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <!--content-->
        @RenderBody()
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <!--footer-->
        @Html.Partial("_footer")
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

***Dashboard.cshtml***

-controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using AcisacWeb.CrossCutting.Dominio.Entidades;
using AcisacWeb.Web.Core.Mantenimiento;
using AcisacWeb.Web.Core.Inicio;
using Acisac.Helper;
using Acisac.Tags;

namespace Acisac.Controllers
{

    public class InicioController : Controller
    {
        string username = Helper.SessionHelper.getUsernameUser();

        TipocambioCore TipocambioCore = new TipocambioCore();
        UsuarioCore UsuarioCore = new UsuarioCore();

        [Autenticado]
        public ActionResult Dashboard()
        {
            TIPO_CAMBIO TIPO_CAMBIO = new TIPO_CAMBIO();
            TIPO_CAMBIO.NESTADO = TipocambioCore.ObtenerEstado("2")[0].NESTADO;
            return View(TIPO_CAMBIO);
            //return View();

        }
}
}
```

-view:

```
@model AcisacWeb.CrossCutting.Dominio.Entidades.TIPO_CAMBIO

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@Styles.Render("~/css/charts")

<!--fila de 4 paneles-->
<div class="row">
    ...
</div>

<script>
    function CargaModal() {
        tipoCambio = '@Model.NESTADO';
        if (tipoCambio == 0) {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    };
</script>

@Scripts.Render("~/js/charts")
@Scripts.Render("~/js/dashboard")
```

**Clientes.cshtml**

-controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using AcisacWeb.CrossCutting.Dominio.Entidades;
using AcisacWeb.Web.Core.Mantenimiento;
using Acisac.Tags;
using AcisacWeb.CrossCutting.Dominio.ViewModels;

namespace Acisac.Controllers
{
    [Autenticado]
    public class MantenimientoController : Controller
    {
        string username = Helper.SessionHelper.getUsernameUser();

        AlmacenCore AlmacenCore = new AlmacenCore();
        AnaquelCore AnaquelCore = new AnaquelCore();

        FamiliaCore FamiliaCore = new FamiliaCore();

        ClienteCore ClienteCore = new ClienteCore();
        ContactoclienteCore ContactoclienteCore = new ContactoclienteCore();
        DireccionclienteCore DireccionclienteCore = new DireccionclienteCore();
        TransporteCore TransporteCore = new TransporteCore();
        TipopersonaCore TipopersonaCore = new TipopersonaCore();
        ProductoCore ProductoCore = new ProductoCore();
        TipocambioCore TipocambioCore = new TipocambioCore();
        UnidadCore UnidadCore = new UnidadCore();
        TipoproductoCore TipoproductoCore = new TipoproductoCore();
        TipomonedaCore TipomonedaCore = new TipomonedaCore();
        TipodocumentopersonaCore TipodocumentopersonaCore = new TipodocumentopersonaCore();
        TipodireccionCore TipodireccionCore = new TipodireccionCore();
        ProveedorCore ProveedorCore = new ProveedorCore();
        MarcaCore MarcaCore = new MarcaCore();
        ImpuestoCore ImpuestoCore = new ImpuestoCore();
        PaisCore PaisCore = new PaisCore();
        EmpleadoCore EmpleadoCore = new EmpleadoCore();
        UbigeoCore UbigeoCore = new UbigeoCore();
        CaracteristicaCore CaracteristicaCore = new CaracteristicaCore();
        ProveedorDatosBancariosCore ProveedorDatosBancariosCore = new ProveedorDatosBancariosCore();
        ProveedorContactoCore ProveedorContactoCore = new ProveedorContactoCore();
        ProveedorDireccionesCore ProveedorDireccionesCore = new ProveedorDireccionesCore();
        SedesCore SedesCore = new SedesCore();
        AreasCore AreasCore = new AreasCore();
        CargosCore CargosCore = new CargosCore();

 public ActionResult Clientes(string PDFINICIO, string PDFFIN)
        {
            List<CLIENTE> clientes = new List<CLIENTE>();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PDFINICIO) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(PDFFIN))
            {
                clientes = ClienteCore.Listar();
                return View(clientes);
            }

            if (!(String.IsNullOrEmpty(PDFINICIO)) && !(String.IsNullOrEmpty(PDFFIN)))
            {
                clientes = ClienteCore.Filtrar(Convert.ToDateTime(PDFINICIO), Convert.ToDateTime(PDFFIN));

                return View(clientes);
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PDFINICIO) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(PDFFIN))
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(PDFINICIO))
                {
                    PDFINICIO = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                    clientes = ClienteCore.Filtrar(Convert.ToDateTime(PDFINICIO), Convert.ToDateTime(PDFFIN));
                    return View(clientes);

                }

                else
                {
                    PDFFIN = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                    clientes = ClienteCore.Filtrar(Convert.ToDateTime(PDFINICIO), Convert.ToDateTime(PDFFIN));
                    return View(clientes);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return View(clientes);
            }


        }
}
}
```

-view:

```
@model IEnumerable<AcisacWeb.CrossCutting.Dominio.Entidades.CLIENTE>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Clientes";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row-lg col-md-12">

    <!--cabecera-->
    <div class="row">
        <h3 class="color-default">Clientes</h3>
        <hr />
    </div>

    ...
</div>
<!--  </div> /.main -->

<!-- DETALLE modal -->
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="large-modalLabel" class="modal fade" id="DETALLE_CLIENTE" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
   ...
</div>

<!-- ELIMINAR modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="ELIMINAR_CLIENTE" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="small-modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    ...
</div>
<!-- -->

@*@Scripts.Render("~/js/cliente")*@
```

Comment: *"is having problems loading*" - this is the relevant part... can you provide more information as to what sort of problems.

Comment: You tagged this [tag:perf], but I don't think you're actually profiling this with the Linux `perf` command.  Revert the tag edit if I skimmed incorrectly.

Comment: Missed the 'white screen' external link as I don't generally click external links.  White screen/no content would not be caused by javascript (except `document.write("")`).  Step through in the debugger might give the error.  It's most likely caused by an issue in the web.config - do you have a different one for for your customer view (in the views/customer subfolder)?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20095946/white-page-with-mvc4-on-iis-7-0

Comment: And this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557730/i-am-getting-a-blank-page-while-deploying-mvc-application-on-iis  (and probably many others if you search for "mvc what causes white screen")